# How do I get a macro to work

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm trying to get voice_enable 0 and voice_enable 1 set as some of my G-keys on a Logitech 510. The only issue is that when I try to use the macro, all it does is make my character jump in place once and it doesn't actually do what it should do; mute the voice channel. Anyone know what it is I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your time, answers are appreciated.

Comment: How, exactly, are you setting your macros?

Comment: In the G-key setup you can have a keypress of a G-key be multiple keystrokes, so I tried setting it that way; having it press the console key, typing out "voice_enable x", enter, then pressing the esc key. I tried fixing it by adding a 0.5 second pause before pressing the space button, but that didn't work.

Comment: open your csgo console, type `bind x incrementvar voice_enable 0 1 1`, bind your g510's G key to `x`

Comment: `incrementvar voice_enable 0 1 1` toggles it between 0 and 1. Also, you can use `voice_scale 0 1 1 instead` to mute sound, but it'll still flash the speaker signs in case you forget to unmute

Comment: Having the macro type into the console seems like a really slow way to do that.  As Kevin says I suggest binding some sort of macro through the console.

Comment: @KevinL you should create an answer with your comment, since it seems to be what solves the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a console command in CS:GO to do this. Macro for it is unnecesary.

Command:

```
bind "key" toggle voice_enable 0 1
```